# Strange issue with ScrollViewer in XAML

Tags: xaml, scrollviewer, textblock

I am trying to place a ScrollViewer around a TextBlock in XAML (here, the textblock is called ImageText). Here is my code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="-20,0,-22,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,64,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Load the image here." VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="555" FontSize="25"/>
    <Button x:Name="LoadButton" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="160" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Click="LoadButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="ExtractButton" Content="Extract" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87" Width="160" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Click="ExtractButton_Click"/>
    <Image x:Name="PreviewImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="296" Margin="76,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ExtractedTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="922,64,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Extracted Text:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" Width="173"/>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ImageText" Margin ="922,100,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text Not Extracted" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="427" Width="380"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

However, when I try to run the program, it for some reason none of the buttons work i.e. I cannot click them, and when I remove the ScrollViewer, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You placed the Margin in the TextBlock instead of the ScrollViewer, change to the following:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin ="922,100,0,0" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="ImageText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text Not Extracted" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="427" Width="380"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And now will work. Anyway instead of doing this like you did I encourage you to use Grid.Rows and Columns or RelativePanel (Windows 10 Apps)